# Python: reading a csv and printing to console. strange characters are being printed

Tags: python, csv

I am reading from a csv file and printing to console in Python. The first printed line is including some odd characters at the beginning of the string. The file in its entirety is:

[image: csv example]

My code is:

```
import csv

with open("C:\\Users\\user\\key.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

the output is:

```
['ï»¿john', '12345']
['jacob', '23456']
['jingle', '34567']
['heimer', '45678']
```

I do not know where the "ï»¿" in the first line is coming from.

Comment: Can you add a hexadecimal representation of the first line of the CSV file?

Comment: I am not too proud to admit I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ï»" is a [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which is used at the beginning of some [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) files or streams to indicate the "endianness" of multi-byte encoding variants (UTF-16 or UTF-32), or, like in this case, to indicate that the file is using UTF-8. Using a BOM at the beginning of a UTF-8 file is optional, but some applications -- like Microsoft Excel -- will use a BOM to indicate that the file is using UTF-8.

If you're using Python 3 and you know that your file will be using UTF-8, you should be able to just add the encoding when you open the file:

```
with open("C:\\Users\\user\\key.csv", encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Here's the Python documentation on this:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data

Comment: Thank you for your input. Works perfectly now.